# node-http-proxy how to match response to request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, proxy, http-proxy

I would like to create a UI which is somehow similar to Telerik's Fiddler. For this purpose, I created a proxy with node-http-proxy which works perfectly :-)

But now I have the problem of how I match the response to my request and I have absolutely no idea what I could try.

Here is my current code:

```
let httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
let connect = require('connect');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let http = require('http');

let proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

let app = connect()
  .use(bodyParser.json()) //json parser
  .use((req, res) => {
    let options = {
      target: "myTargetHere"
    };

    proxy.web(req, res, options);
  });

http.createServer(app).listen(8000);

proxy.on("proxyReq", (proxyReq, req, res) => {
  if (req.body) {
    let bodyData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    let bodyLength = Buffer.byteLength(bodyData)
    proxyReq.setHeader("Content-Length", bodyLength);
    proxyReq.write(bodyData);
  }
});

proxy.on('proxyRes', (proxyRes, req, res) => {
  let body = new Buffer.alloc(0);
  let bodyLength = 0;

  proxyRes.on('data' , data => {
      process.stdout.write("c ");
      body = Buffer.concat([body, data]);
  });
  proxyRes.on("end", () => {
    bodyLength = Buffer.byteLength(body);
    body = body.toString();
    console.log("response body length: ", bodyLength);
  });
});
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can match the response in `proxy.on('proxyRes', ...)` with my request in `proxy.on('proxyReq', ...)`? Is there something that is unique within every request/response?

Comment: would the `req` be the same? I tried following the code in http-proxy but lost interest :p